# Heat Map for Code Repository Check-ins

Tags: svn, refactoring, repository, heatmap

Is there a good tool for looking through a code repository and finding the places that have the most changes per checkin?

It may be useful for finding bugs, or places to refactor code.

Currently I use SVN, but any other solutions would be considered.  Thanks!

Comment: do you mean finding *files* that have most changes per checkin? because it is difficult to both analyze source code and calculate numbers of checkin in one app.

Comment: Note: I work with OP and was standing next to him while he posted. File would give a good pointer, but less than 100% ideal. The *point* of this is to help our intake of rescue projects and try to quickly figure out where the most problematic pieces of code are likely to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org) will meet your needs.

A top-level list of the features:

Timeline for the lines of code
Lines of code for each developer
Activity by Clock time
Authors Activity
Author activity per Module
Author Most Recent Commits with links to ViewVc
Stats per directory
File count
Average file size
Largest files
Files with most revisions
Directory Sizes
Repository Tags Number of LOC per version.
Repository tree with file count and lines of code
LOC and Churn the evolution of LOC and the amount of change per day
Repo Map the dynamic hierarchical view of your repo for the last 30 days

Specifically, there is LOC graphed versus churn:
http://statsvn.org/statsvn/churn.html

And there is a "heat map" which allows you to drill down into the places in the code most often changed, which I believe was your #1 request:
http://statsvn.org/statsvn/repomap.html

The samples I've linked to aren't the greatest, but we've used the tool and it is extremely elegant and powerful.

Comment: Thank you very much - this looks like a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news is that there is no such tool. Good news is that you can write it by yourself and make your valuable contribution.

Anyway, there are similar tools, such as [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) that partly perform the task of source code analysis. Even though those tools could be applied only if you program in Java, but there are alternatives for other languages too (Resharper, YASCA, PHP_CodeSniffer, etc). Low chances these tools could be used for finding places with most frequent changes, but will definitely help to improve code quality (it seems that code quality concern is the primary for asking your question).

Comment: Note: I work with OP and was standing next to him when he posted. The tools you mention are definitely in our arsenal. The overarching point is that we take in projects that are disasters. Ideally we want an automated way to tell us "hey, look *there* it's probably bad code." We're hoping to add "places that got far more edits than others" to our list of places that are worth investigating manually.